# ¿Cómo puedo crear un vector y agregarle valores en orden al azar como si fuera una muestra?

Tags: r

Estoy necesitando crear un vector de longitud 1M con cien mil valores iguales a 1 y el resto, a 0, para luego extraer una muestra de tamaño 1000 de ahí y evaluar la proporción de c/u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `sample()` para generar la muestra:

```
sample(0:1, 1000000, replace=TRUE)
```

Con esta función puedes generar desde una vector de muestra `0:1`, una `n` cantidad de valores, importante en este caso usar `replace=TRUE` para repetir valores, la generación va a ser aleatoria con una distribución uniforme, eventualmente podrías asignar una probabilidad a cada valor, usando el parámetro `prob`.

La selección luego de una muestra, se puede hacer también con `sample()` pero esta vez para randomizar los índices que se usarán para seleccionar los datos:

```
x <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace=TRUE)
muestra <- x[sample(1:1000000, 100)] # una muestra de 100 elementos
```

Comment: Genial. Pero en ese caso como podría hacer para que solo el 10% de los valores sean igual a 1 y el restante 90% igual a 0 ?

Comment: Ahí complementé la edición: `sample(0:1, 1000000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9, 0.1))`